# How to display Unity realtime TIFF (RAW, NEF) images?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, tiff, raw

During execution, I load photos from the memory of the Android device, through LoadImage everything works with PNG and JPG, but how to display TIFF (RAW, NEF)?

Tried using LoadRavItageDate(), nothing happens. Apparently not correctly determine the encoding and dimensions.
Could you suggest a solution! I tried to convert in real time to a readable format, it did not work either.
Thank you!